# nftables, add output rule syntax

Tags: linux, netfilter, nftables

I'm a bit frustrated by the lack of comprehensive documentation of nftables and currently I'm failing to get even a simple example to work. I'm trying just create a output rule. Here's my only table:

```
root@localhost ~ # nft list ruleset
table inet filter {
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }
}
```

I wish to count the number of packets sent to 8.8.8.8. So I used the example command from the nftables wiki (https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Simple_rule_management):

```
root@localhost ~ # nft add rule filter output ip daddr 8.8.8.8 counter                       
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
add rule filter output ip daddr 8.8.8.8 counter
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But for some reason, I get very uninformative error message. What am I doing wrong and what is the correct way to add an output rule?

```
root@localhost ~ # uname -a                                                                    
Linux localhost 4.15.3-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 15 00:13:49 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@localhost ~ # nft --version
nftables v0.8.2 (Joe Btfsplk)
root@localhost ~ # lsmod|grep '^nf'                                                          
nfnetlink_queue        28672  0
nfnetlink_log          20480  0
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv6    16384  1 ip6t_MASQUERADE
nf_nat_ipv6            16384  1 ip6table_nat
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4    16384  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 36864  4 nf_nat_masquerade_ipv6,nf_nat_ipv6,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv4
nft_reject_inet        16384  0
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 nft_reject_inet
nf_reject_ipv6         16384  1 nft_reject_inet
nft_reject             16384  1 nft_reject_inet
nft_meta               16384  0
nf_conntrack_ipv6      16384  2
nf_defrag_ipv6         36864  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  2
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nft_ct                 20480  0
nf_conntrack          155648  10 nft_ct,nf_conntrack_ipv6,nf_conntrack_ipv4,ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv6,nf_nat_ipv6,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,ip6t_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat
nft_set_bitmap         16384  0
nft_set_hash           28672  0
nft_set_rbtree         16384  0
nf_tables_inet         16384  2
nf_tables_ipv6         16384  1 nf_tables_inet
nf_tables_ipv4         16384  1 nf_tables_inet
nf_tables             106496  10 nft_ct,nft_set_bitmap,nft_reject,nft_set_hash,nf_tables_ipv6,nf_tables_ipv4,nft_reject_inet,nft_meta,nft_set_rbtree,nf_tables_inet
nfnetlink              16384  3 nfnetlink_log,nfnetlink_queue,nf_tables
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct command is

```
root@localhost ~ # nft add rule inet filter output ip daddr 8.8.8.8 counter
```

Notice the `inet` prefix before the table name (`filter`). That's the table's family type. It's optional, but if you omit it, nft assumes `ip` (= IPv4), but I'm using `inet` pseudo-family (both IPv4 and IPv6).

I learned this thanks to the people in the `#netfilter` channel on Freenode.

Needless to say that nft error messages are anything but helpful. :-)